# Confused with use of strpos and !==

Tags: php, strpos

Confused!
I am trying to extract our localsites' names which are embedded in our WordPress website's structure, ie https://www.website.co.uk/site99/folderX/page.  In the URL the localsite name is all lower case without any gaps, whereas the 'display name' of the localsite has a Starting capital and a gap between words.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site01/') !== false) { $categoryIdOrSlug = 'Site 01';}
elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site02/') !== false) { $categoryIdOrSlug = 'Site 02';}
elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site03/') !== false) { $categoryIdOrSlug = 'Site 03';}
endif;
```

so what I am looking for is where /site99/ is in position 0 of the slug.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem/question?

Comment: Please check the documentation before asking something here. It is [clearly documented](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#example-5844) why we should be using `!==` instead of `!=`. If this is not what you are asking, please update your question to reflect what you are actually asking us.

Comment: Hi JJJ, the problem is that $categoryIdOrSlug is not being populated with the site description, ie when the url is www.website.co.uk/site01/pageA, $categoryIdOrSlug is not being populated with 'Site 01' or when www.website.co.uk/site02/pageA with 'Site 02'.

Comment: Hi Tom, yes I know !== and != is documented and I believe the above code snippet is the correct use of !==, if I didn't I would not be asking the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you are in `https://www.website.co.uk/site99/folderX/page`

Then : `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will be `/site99/folderX/page`

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site98/') !== false) { $categoryIdOrSlug = 'Site 98';} // strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site98/') will be false
elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site99/') !== false) { $categoryIdOrSlug = 'Site 99';} // strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site98/') will be 0 (which is success run & is true)
```

**See different outputs:**

```
echo strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site99/'); // OUTPUT: 0
```

Here, `strpos()` return the index/position at which the 2nd param(`/site99/`) is present in first param(`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`).

The `strpos()` function finds the position of the first occurrence of a string inside another string. Related functions: `strrpos()` - Finds the position of the last occurrence of a string inside another string (case-sensitive)

```
var_dump(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site98/'));
```

Output will be `bool(false)`. Why its `false` because the string was not found in param one. If its found, then the out will be a `int` of position like `int(25)`.

```
var_dump(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site99/'));
```

Output will be `int(0)` because `strpos()` has successfully found `/site99/` in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

And, normally `===` or `!==` are used for Boolean value(`TRUE/FALSE`) comparisons.

No need to get confused with `strpos()` and `!==` both are entirely different, one returns a position index value(if found) or `FALSE`, if not found required string. Whereas, `!==` compares left & right side values of operator & says `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

*Reply to your comment:*

Yes, you are getting correct answer. As you said to making ensure we are using `if()` check.

You see we are getting `int(0)` while `var_dump(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site99/'));`. If we have a index value(even its 0) its treated as a success run(`true`). That is, the string you are searching **is found in index 0 or at a particular position of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`**. `if()` makes sure that the check is correct, `int(0) !== false` means `int(0)` is a success run(which is also said as `true`). So `if(int(0) !== false)` can be said also as `if(true !== false)` which is `true` & so `$categoryIdOrSlug = 'Site 99';` will run.

`if()` can also be written as:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site98/')) { $categoryIdOrSlug = 'Site 98';}
elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site99/')) { $categoryIdOrSlug = 'Site 99';}

echo $categoryIdOrSlug; // output: Site 99
```

**You cant check by `=== 0`** because we cant say the position at which `strpos()` founds the searching string, it may vary.

Comment: Does $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] not returned the URL after the domain? ie '/site99/folderX/page' the relative path from the root

Reading your answer above my code should work as strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/site99/') should return int(0). To ensure I get the right answer, I need to use !== FALSE ?  

If I used === 0, the 'if' would resolve to TRUE if the 2nd param was '/site99/' as it would be position int(0) AND if the 2nd param was '/site98/', as the text is not present it return 0/false which would also resolve to TRUE when tested by === 0. 
Correct or have I missed something?

Comment: @ChristopherHilling: I have edited my answer & commented on `if()` please read those.